# How to estimate potential income of using AdMob in the app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, ads, in-app-billing

At this time i have few paid features in android app. I'd like to estimate potential income of using AdMob ads in the app and choose the best strategy: paid features or ads.

Comment: this really depends on the type of app you are releasing and how the ads interact with the user. https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/111/ although has a quick overview for monetizing strategies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's quite impossible as far as I know to really estimate things like this. 
Your payment rate in Admob depends on a lot of things like fillrate and click-rate, but in general you can be sure it will be pretty low. 
Basically you're talking about figures as low as 0.04 dollar per 1000 views.

However, the real question is if your features/app are worth paying for, especially assuming that your app and developer account aren't well known and you're not picked out by Google into the spotlight of the first page.

Basically this is all up to your own judgement, but as I see it the choice to make when looking for max income, would be to do both.

If you look at most games (Take per example Angry Birds, Ruzzle, Wordfeud, DrawSomething etc) they launch both options: 1 with ads so people can try your app out, and 1 paid version for the -much smaller - group of people that are willing to pay.

The same ofcourse can be used with in-app payment features, by simply adding a feature to discard the banners when bought.

Comment: yes, i thought about releasing full version with all the features and ads and version with in-app billing but without ads. so the question is how much will i get for ads.

Comment: > 0.04 dollar per 1000 views. do you mean activity views or ads views? as AFAIK ads are downloaded and spinned in the same place in the app and one activity view means few ads views

Comment: > depends on a lot of things. The app is leading in it's topic but the topic is not so big. So the app has about 30K installations and 120K activities views in a year.

Comment: With views i mean how many times your app serves an ad. So, if you leave 1 activity open for 1 minute and refresh the ad every 30 seconds, you have 2 views.

Typically the income, in my experience, is between 0.04 and 0.11 dollar per 1000 views, so from there on you can estimate a range of your possible max and min income i suppose. 
To know for sure, there is only one way: try it. 

Good luck.